# Python matplotlib: Removing "Configure subplots" tool from toolbar in matplotlib causes an error

Tags: python, matplotlib, toolbar

I have a plot using `matplotlib` and I want to remove some of the buttons from the toolbar.

I have achieved removing the forward, back, home, zoom and help buttons, but when I try to remove the "`Configure subplots`" button I get an error.

**Why can't I remove this one but I can remove the others?**

My code is something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'

fig = plt.figure()

fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('forward')
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('back')
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('home')
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('zoom')
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('help')
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('subplots')
```

If I comment the last line, the code runs without problem and I get the toolbar without the specified buttons, but if I add the last line I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

I have tried all type of combinations from '`subplots`', in case the name is not correct like

- '`Subplot`',
- '`Subplots`',
- '`subplot`',
- '`configure`',
- '`configure_subplots`',
- '`Configure subplots`'

Comment: I suggested a fix for this in [#14282](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14282), which might make it into the next bug fix release.

Comment: In the meantime you can use the Qt5Agg backend, which does not have this problem.