# Removing "help" tool from Matplotlib toolbar causes: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Tags: python, matplotlib, azure-devops, toolbar

In my ubuntu 18.04 VM with Python 3.7.7 and matplotlib 3.3.1 this code works without error:

```
    plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'
    fig = plt.figure()
    tm = fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
    tm.remove_tool('help') # Fails here in ubuntu in Azure!
```

But when the same code is called from a unittest in my Azure DevOps build pipeline, it fails at `tm.remove_tool('help')` on the `ubuntu-18.04` Microsoft-hosted VM with:

```
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.9/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_managers.py", line 228, in remove_tool
    tool.destroy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

This happens in both Python 3.6.12 and 3.7.9 on the `ubuntu-18.04` Azure VM. Both are using matplotlib 3.3.1 as well.

However the same code runs without error in Windows on a `windows-2019` Microsoft-hosted VM in both Python 3.6.8 and 3.7.9, also both on matplotlib 3.3.1.

Has anyone else seen this and got a fix or workaround please? Unfortunately I can't reproduce this on my own ubuntu VM.

Maybe the Microsoft-hosted `ubuntu-18.04` VM is missing something matplotlib needs? Or there's a weird matplotlib bug?  I didn't see this issue in Azure when I was on matplotlib 3.1.1.

**Update on 2 Sept 2020**

After adding the line `print("Tools: %s" % tm._tools)` after initialising `tm` I find that `tm._tools` is a dict with many entries on Windows in Azure (and `tm._tools['help']` is a `matplotlib.backends._backend_tk.HelpTk` object). But in Linux on Azure `tm._tools` is an empty dict: `{}`!

So do I need to do something extra for matplotlib in Linux? The packages on the 18.04 ubuntu VM used by Azure are listed [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) and include these, if it helps:

- libgtk-3-0
- tk

**Update on 5 Aug 2021**

Running this fixes the issue in my own ubuntu VM:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

I think it installs the back-end libraries for Tcl/Tk (see [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installlinux)). But unfortunately this fix does not cure the error in the `ubuntu-18.04` Azure VM.

Comment: it seems it can't find button `help` and it gets `None` so later t tries to do `None.destroy()`. What if you remove line `tm.remove_tool('help')` - do you see button on screen ? Maybe it doesn't have this button.

Comment: It certainly has the help button in my laptop's ubuntu VM if I remove `tm.remove_tool('help')` and add `plt.show()`. But I have no idea what happens in the Azure ubuntu VM because I can't access it; it only exists for the lifetime of my build job. The only way to debug that is to add new code or print statements and wait to see what the build output is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest - do you think my issue has anything to do with https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14282 because it looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56220821/1843329) reported on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Tcl/Tk won't work on an ubuntu Azure DevOps VM unless a virtual display server is running in the background, such as Xvfb. You also need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to point at this display. See my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72129215/1843329) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer as to why Azure is doing this sadly.
Though, as a workaround you could always explore plotting the figure without the toolbar, depending on your needs.

something like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

data = [i for i in range(5)]

window = tk.Tk()

artist = Figure()
artist.add_subplot().plot(data)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(artist, master=window)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I've inherited a large amount of code from someone else. The real app is much bigger and has a customised toolbar, so adopting a fresh approach would involve significant rework.

Comment: btw: simpler `data = list(range(5))`