# How to use TkAgg backend for matplotlib in ubuntu image on Azure Devops?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, tkinter, azure-devops

My matplotlib code is failing in ubuntu VMs in Azure DevOps; whereas the same code works in Azure Windows VMs and on my own ubuntu VM. This boiled-down Azure pipeline YAML reproduces the issue:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-18.04

variables:
  python.version: '3.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
    addToPath: true
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- bash: |
    pip install --upgrade pip &&
    pip install matplotlib &&
    pip list
  displayName: 'Install required packages'

- bash: |
    sudo apt-get install python3-tk
  displayName: 'Install Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import tkinter
      print('Tcl/Tk version: {}'.format(tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')))
  displayName: 'Report Tcl/Tk version'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import matplotlib
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      
      print("Using: " + matplotlib.get_backend())
      
      plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'
      
      fig = plt.figure()
      ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
      
      tm = fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
      tm.remove_tool('help')
  displayName: 'Remove help button from toolbar'
```

When the pipeline runs, it reports matplotlib 3.5.2 and Tcl/Tk version 8.6.8 are installed on the VM. But the final task fails with:

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/5e3dce70-dff2-405e-b5ef-8dac88d22243.py:6: UserWarning: Treat the new Tool classes introduced in v1.5 as experimental for now; the API and rcParam may change in future versions.
  plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'
/home/vsts/work/_temp/5e3dce70-dff2-405e-b5ef-8dac88d22243.py:13: UserWarning: ToolManager does not control tool help
  tm.remove_tool('help')
Using: agg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vsts/work/_temp/5e3dce70-dff2-405e-b5ef-8dac88d22243.py", line 13, in <module>
    tm.remove_tool('help')
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.12/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_managers.py", line 210, in remove_tool
    tool.destroy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

Note the printed backend for matplotlib is `agg` rather than `TkAgg`. The same Python code works in my own ubuntu 18.04 VM after running `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`, and the code then reports `TkAgg` there.

So why doesn't this work in ubuntu in Azure DevOps? It looks like Tcl/Tk is not being installed or configured properly in the ubuntu VM.

**Update**
If I insert `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` after `import matplotlib` then the output does say `Using: TkAgg`. But I get this error instead at the `fig = plt.figure()` line:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

I've tried setting the environment variables DISPLAY and MPLBACKEND as well, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to create a virtual display for Tcl/Tk to work correctly on the remote Azure DevOps VMs. I used [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), as that's already installed on the ubuntu 18.04 agent (as per [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-Readme.md)). You also need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to point at the virtual display. Here's what worked for me in the end:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-18.04

variables:
  python.version: '3.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
    addToPath: true
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- bash: |
    pip install matplotlib &&
    pip list
  displayName: 'Install required packages'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import tkinter
      print('Tcl/Tk version: {}'.format(tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')))
  displayName: 'Report Tcl/Tk version'

- bash: |
    Xvfb :1 -screen 0 640x480x16 &
  displayName: 'Create virtual display'

- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DISPLAY]:1.0"
  displayName: 'Set DISPLAY'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import matplotlib
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      
      print("Using: " + matplotlib.get_backend())
      
      plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'
      
      fig = plt.figure()
      ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
      
      tm = fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager
      tm.remove_tool('help')
  displayName: 'Remove help button from toolbar'
```

The output of the final task was then:

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/b7d18caa-56d0-4438-9d8c-b6bbaa04935b.py:10: UserWarning: Treat the new Tool classes introduced in v1.5 as experimental for now; the API and rcParam may change in future versions.
  plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'
Using: TkAgg
```

Note matplotlib automatically detects the TkAgg backend; you don't have to tell it to use it. Two gotchas that caught me out: Xvfb starts with a capital X; and make sure you run it in the background!